# KieBuilder too much time to load kieFileSystem and build

Tags: performance, jboss, drools, kie

I have a Drools based application, which has 15-20 files overall. Each file has rules for a particular context. I load the file in session based on the context I want to invoke. Recently the number of executions increased a lot which was followed by latency degradation. I found that building KieBuilder is taking a long time, which grows proportionally to the number of requests on the application. Based on some research, it looks like all calls stop at the building step and continue when building is complete for all. I am not sure why this is happening since the calls are disconnected in the sense that all need different files to be loaded.
I found some references to KieBuilder taking too much time but couldn't find any solution.

Drools version being used: 7.4.1-Final

My code:

```
private StatelessKieSession loadSession(final String namespace, final String path) {
        final KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        final KieResources kieResources = kieServices.getResources();
        final KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();

        final InputStream ruleFile = ruleStore.getRulesForRuleId(namespace, path);

        kieFileSystem.write(kieResources.newInputStreamResource(ruleFile)
                        .setSourcePath(DRL_PATH)
                        .setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL));
        log.info("Creating KieBuilder for {}/{}", namespace, path);
        final KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem).buildAll();
        if (kieBuilder.getResults().hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
            throw new InvalidRulesException("Failed to load rules from S3 in "
                    + "Drools engine with error: " + kieBuilder.getResults().toString());
        }
        log.info("Created KieBuilder for {}/{}", namespace, path);

        final KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(
                kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());

        return kContainer.newStatelessKieSession();
    }
```

Line taking too long:

```
        final KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem).buildAll();
```

Logs showing application is just waiting for 20 secs for KieBuilder :

```
(http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-95) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/CafeteriaTimings.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:10,904 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-92) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/MandatoryOffDays.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:10,911 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-82) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/ConsecutiveOffDaysPerWeek.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:10,912 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-93) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/MaxWorkingHoursPerSiteWeek.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:10,916 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-53) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/MaxTimeBetweenStartAndLunch.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:10,916 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-79) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/MaxWorkingHoursPerDay.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:10,922 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-97) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/BreakFrequency.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:10,924 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-86) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/MaxTimeBetweenStartAndBreak.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:11,004 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-90) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/CanLunchExistOutsideCafeteriaTime.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:11,004 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-87) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/LunchDuration.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:11,004 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-94) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/MaxConsecutiveDays.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:11,005 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-83) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/LunchFrequency.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:11,010 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-85) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/MinOffDaysPerWeek.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:11,015 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-88) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/MaxWorkingHoursPerWeek.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:11,017 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-84) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/MinWorkHoursBeforeLunch.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:11,018 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-96) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/BreakDuration.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:11,022 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-89) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/WorkIntervalsList.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:11,032 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-99) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:11,037 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-80) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/MinTimeBetweenStartAndBreak.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:11,104 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-78) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/MinConsecutiveOffWorkHours.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:11,108 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-81) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Creating KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/DayValidationType.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:11,203 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-100) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:11,322 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-2) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:14,324 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-1) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:15,224 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-3) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:16,207 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-4) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:16,404 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-6) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:16,503 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-5) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:17,003 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-7) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:17,203 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-8) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:18,513 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-9) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:19,122 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-10) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:19,803 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-11) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:19,903 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-12) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:20,114 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-13) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:20,213 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-14) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:20,407 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-15) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:20,703 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-16) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:21,303 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-17) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:21,503 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-18) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:21,603 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-19) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:21,603 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-20) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:23,711 (MetricAggregationClientScheduled-1) com.amazon.aws.cloudwatch.extension.client.impl.MetricAggregationCloudWatchClient: flush is invoked with sync false
12 Jan 2021 10:36:24,308 (MetricAggregationClientPublisher-1) com.amazon.aws.cloudwatch.extension.client.impl.MetricAggregationCloudWatchClient: Stats after submit are {}
12 Jan 2021 10:36:24,905 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-21) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:25,703 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-22) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:26,518 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-23) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:26,603 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-24) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:26,903 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-25) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:27,218 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-26) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:27,403 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-27) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:28,803 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-28) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:29,503 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-29) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:29,903 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-30) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:30,129 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-31) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:30,803 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-32) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:31,819 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-34) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:31,902 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-33) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:32,103 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-35) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:32,203 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-36) org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher: PathInfo: /ping
12 Jan 2021 10:36:32,219 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-90) org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl: KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=org.default:drl54:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
12 Jan 2021 10:36:32,322 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-90) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Created KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/CanLunchExistOutsideCafeteriaTime.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:32,613 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-82) org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl: KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=org.default:drl80:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
12 Jan 2021 10:36:32,613 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-82) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Created KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/ConsecutiveOffDaysPerWeek.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:33,913 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-79) org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl: KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=org.default:drl76:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
12 Jan 2021 10:36:33,913 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-79) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Created KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/MaxWorkingHoursPerDay.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:34,205 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-92) org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl: KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=org.default:drl0:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
12 Jan 2021 10:36:34,205 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-92) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Created KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/MandatoryOffDays.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:34,210 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-95) org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl: KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=org.default:drl92:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
12 Jan 2021 10:36:34,210 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-95) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Created KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/CafeteriaTimings.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:34,608 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-81) org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl: KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=org.default:drl31:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
12 Jan 2021 10:36:34,609 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-81) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Created KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/DayValidationType.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:34,615 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-85) org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl: KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=org.default:drl8:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
12 Jan 2021 10:36:34,615 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-85) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Created KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/MinOffDaysPerWeek.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:34,716 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-87) org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl: KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=org.default:drl79:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
12 Jan 2021 10:36:34,716 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-87) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Created KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/LunchDuration.drl
12 Jan 2021 10:36:35,218 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-94) org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl: KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=org.default:drl94:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
12 Jan 2021 10:36:35,218 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-94) com.amazon.wforuleengine.drools.RulesSessionFactory: Created KieBuilder for scheduling/amazon/cs/MaxConsecutiveDays.drl
```

I am looking to understand why the time taken for KieBuilder is proportional to the number of calls, and for a way to optimize on the time taken.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about what you mean by "the time taken ... is proportional to the number of calls?" Do you mean that if you call this logic X times, each time will take longer than the previous time?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If I call 5 times, it takes around 5-6secs. If I call 20 times, it takes 20-22 secs

Comment: In the log there's written "Failed to load rules from S3", why?

Comment: @LucaMolteni We are using S3 to store the DRL files. But we do not see that exception ever. The call does get completed successfully, the issue is just about latency of KieBuilder.

Comment: @confusedCoder when you can buildAll, the KieBuilder strictly read all the files in memory see https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/996e8f40dec9f25650dfb0457eb09bad3b1cebc7/drools-compiler/src/main/java/org/drools/compiler/kie/builder/impl/KieBuilderImpl.java#L308 so could it be S3 throttling you?

Comment: @LucaMolteni there is no issue with S3 as the call to load files doesn't take much time. What do you mean by "KieBuilder strictly read all the files in memory"? I am specifically giving it the file to load as InputStream. Why would it care about what is in application memory?